# remove lines from fileA.csv depending on entries of first column of fileB.csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have been handed two files from a preprocessing pipeline.

```
#fileA.csv
87687,"institute Polytechnic, Brazil"
342424,"university of India, India"
24343,"univefrsity columbia, Bogata, Colombia"
82739, "Hero univetsity, greece"
....
<3million lines>
```

```
#fileB.csv
342424
82739
...
<some 2 million entries>
```

I want to filter `fileA.csv` from `fileB.csv` as in, I want to keep the lines which match `fileB.csv`(these are IDs) in column 1 of `fileA.csv`. in other words, for each in row in `fileA.csv` if the first column entry is not present in `fileB.csv`, delete the line.

I am not exactly sure how to go about this in bash (which id prefer) rather than writing this in python (for each row, see if first entry is in list of IDs and filter).

In the above trivial example, the output would just be:

```
#result.csv
342424,"university of India, India"
82739, "Hero univetsity, greece"
```

In python, id do (pseudocode):

```
fileBlist=<load fileB.csv>
for item in fileAcsv:
   x=item[0]
   yesy_no=x in fileB_list
   <append entry>
```

*UPDATE*

I have tried the solutions posted but there seems to be some inconsistency (maybe it is my fault!). So,:

```
fileB.csv has 29206428 lines
fileA.csv has 32128236 lines.
```

I was hoping to see the result file to contain 29206428 lines, but instead the result file is 30932039 lines. This seems logically impossible( `in other words, for each in row in fileA.csv if the first column entry is not present in fileB.csv, delete the line.`) :D and I wonder what is going on..

Comment: does `fileB.csv` always contain only a single column?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes

Comment: Once again, the most frequently asked question in this forum appears....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { exists[$1]; next }
         $1 in exists' fileB.csv fileA.csv > result.csv

cat result.csv

342424,"university of India, India"
82739, "Hero univetsity, greece"
```

Comment: thank you.. I am trying to move away from python and become cmd expert :D so this is super helpfule!

Comment: It kinda seems to give me an incorrect number of entries in output. I have posted my update on the main post.

Comment: I have checked your update. For debugging I suggest you make a small set of data from both files and post it in question. We can then see where is the issue.

Comment: I have found out what the problem was.. just that there were duplicate entries with different second column.. Its all good, thank you for your help and patience. So essentially for the same id, I had multiple second column entries.

Answer (score 2):

you can sort the files, then use `join`:

```
sort -t, -k1,1 fileA.csv > fileA_sorted.csv
sort -t, -k1,1 fileB.csv > fileB_sorted.csv
join -t, -1 1 -2 1 fileA_sorted.csv fileB_sorted.csv > result.csv
```

This is using the same format for the files as you shared above.

Answer (score 1):

##### With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{arr[$1];next} ($1 in arr)' fileB.csv fileA.csv | tee result.csv
```

The file size is only ~ 15MB for the one with 'just' `id`s

```
printf '%s\n' {1..2000000} >> fileB
du -h fileB
15M fileB
```

##### output

```
$ cat result.csv
342424,"university of India, India"
82739, "Hero univetsity, greece"
```

Comment: I have posted an updated.. something seems to be off :(

Comment: ah the order needed to be flipped. So, `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{arr[$1];next} ($1 in arr)' fileA.csv fileB.csv` seems to give the correct number of entries

Comment: wait, no :((( when I reverse it I get only the ids and nothing else.. damn